# How to use BeautifulSoup to delete HTML content on wiki page [Python script]

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a python script that updates a list of existing vms onto my ADO wiki page. I need to add additional code, in the script, that deletes the existing content on the wiki page first, before it then updates the page with the list of existing vms.

I've found that the content tag is where all the data, that I'm interested in, is stored.

The HTML output for my wiki page is:

```
<script id="dataProviders" type="application/json">{"data":{".... ,"content":"|virtual machine name | ADO ticket | owner Email | creation date |\n|--|--|--|--|\n| my-12345-vm-0 | #12345 | hi.work@gmail.com | 29-01-2024 |"},
```

I am using BeautifulSoup module on python to help with the removal of this content, but I can't get it to work right. Below is just a part of the script i.e. the function that is being used to delete the content on the wiki page:

```
def wiki_delete(vm_list):
     pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
     pat = get_or_set_secret(kv_url, pat_secret_name, " ")
     authorization = base64.b64encode(f":{pat}".encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
     basic_auth_value = f"Basic {authorization}"
     get_headers = {"Authorization": basic_auth_value} 
    
     get_response = requests.get(wiki_url, verify=True, headers=get_headers)
     #existing_content = get_response()["content"]
     print(get_response.content)
     
     if get_response.status_code == 200:
         print(get_response.status_code)
         existing_content = get_response.json()["content"]
         soup = BeautifulSoup(existing_content, 'html.parser')
         page_text = soup.get_text()
         print(page_text)
         to_be_removed = soup.find('script', {'content': page_text})
         if to_be_removed:
            to_be_removed.extract()
         modified_html = str(soup)
         print(modified_html)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?